# Is it possible to create a global constant char array in C#?

Tags: arrays, variables, 2d, constants

I am making a game board through a 2D char array and I want it to be a global array. I've done this in Java, where I've declared it as:

static char[][] gameboard; //Gameboard array

But it is not working in C#. I'm new to C# and I don't know why the compiler wont accept.

const char[,] gameBoard;

I tried to make the value of it null, but it doesn't let my program run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# doesn't support global variables outside of type definitions. So you would need to write something like this:

```cs
public class Gameboard {
    const char[,] gameBoard;  // const values are implicitly static in C#
}
```

You would then access gameBoard with `Gameboard.gameBoard`.